# Cannot initiate to Oracle Spatial Studio to my Oracle Cloud ADW studio-schema

Tags: oracle-spatial

I am trying to work with Oracle Spatial Studio actually from Marketplace remotely to my OracleADB spatial_studio_repo: [image]

[image]

[image]

But the initialization process does not work on the spatial_studio_repo schema -
I checked the connection with the right wallet.zip - ok, the grants incl. spatial_studio grants and
unlimited tablespace.. are correct.

I cannot find the issue.

[image]

Thanks, Friedhold.

Comment: Friedhold, are you trying to re-use, in this new studio installation, a repository already in use by another or previous studio installation ?

Comment: Thanks Albert, I don't have another user in this ADW DB - good point is to find the user like SPATIAL_STUDIO_% ;-).  It seems there is a difference in David Lapps installation for me: https://blogs.oracle.com/database/post/oracle-spatial-studio-221-now-on-cloud-marketplace :: my db already exists and I created the SPATIAL_STUDIO_REPO user before.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Spatial Studio deployed correctly and you can access your existing ADB using the wallet from your machine right?, try verifying your ADW is visible to your Studio compute instance, by the looks of if perhaps your ADW is not public or (if private) its ACL doesn't allow connections from your compute's network.

Comment: Yes, Spatial Studio is deployed correctly as a cloud instance and I can access my ADB SPATIAL-STUDIO_REPO user from SQLdeveloper using the wallet. It seems to me that the studio cannot find the DB server inside this cloud stack, but precisely that is my weak point I have no idea how to allow connection from the cloud studio instance to the cloud ADW db.
I would appreciate a tip here, thanks.

Comment: How did you deploy both the ADB and Studio?, is the ADB private (with ACL/subnet filter) or public?, and how was Studio deployed? i.e. to an existing subnet (public/private?) or a new vcn? what did you select on the configure autonomous database section of the marketplace deployment?.

Comment: Try logging to your compute, upload the wallet and do sqlplus (already in studio's compute) to verify the connection, if that fails then you need to login to your OCI console and check Studio subnet's nsg rules, and if your ADW is private then check its ACL.

Comment: Following Network info of my ADW DB :
Access type:             Allow secure access from everywhere
Access control list:   Disabled Mutual TLS (mTLS) authentication: Required 

I will try to start the process again with a new ADW and new VCN to scan the steps. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have now successfully created Oracle Spatial Studio from the Marketplace:
it works for me when I create a new VCN and a new ADW while building the studio stack.

Friedhold

Comment: Good. So it was just a connectivity issue between the studio stack and your ADW.

Answer (score 0):

To correctly deploy Spatial Studio from the Marketplace, you have to select a *_LOW service when you specify the metadata schema details. Otherwise, the creation of the repository will fail.